# Autocompletion on multiple words in a text box

Tags: winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I'd like to create a simple *winforms* application, that enables simple&fast text input on a given topic.

My plan is to have a small db with frequently used words by the user on a given topic (e.g. some technical terms of his job) and when he is typing, an autocomlete feature advises word completion from a drop down list, like in an intellisense editor. As I know .net winforms autcompletion can be used only for a word, not 'dynamically'. It would be like predictive SMS typing in a mobile phone.

I know there are some open source intellisense controls, but as I see they does not fit my requirements, they are specifically for programming languages, not for any type of text.

Do you have any suggestions about open-source projects on this topic?

Thanks in advance!

.net4/c#/vs2010/winforms

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial is for a text file auto completion but it's a good starting point if you want to create your own control for it.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/34785-create-an-autocomplete-textbox-control-in-c%23/

Comment: Thanks, but as I see it does the same as the standard autocomplete text box, nothing more, just some complete word list loading from a file...